# Object added in Parse several times after checking for all non similar objects:

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am querying objects from Parse, that I then append into an array. I check if this array contains a particular object, if not, I wish to add this particular object to Parse.
However, for each different object in this array, and therefore in Parse, the particular object gets added. 
For instance, if I have four different objects, the object in question will be added four times.
See my code below:

```
      @IBAction func nextWeek(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.viewHeight.constant = 93
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }, completion: nil)

    var array2 = [String]()

    var query1 = PFQuery(className: "sendMessage")
    query1.whereKey("messageSent", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query1.whereKey("messageReceived", equalTo:self.nameLabel.text!)
    query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects1, NSError) -> Void in

        if let objects1 = objects1 as? [PFObject] {

                for object1 in objects1 {

                    if object1["message"] != nil {

                        var textMessage3: String = object1["message"] as! String

                        var message3 = Message(sender: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, message: textMessage3, time: NSDate())

                        array2.append(message3.message)

                 if contains(array2, self.nextWeekButtonL.titleLabel!.text!) {

                        } else {



                    println(array2)

                            println("it does not contain")

                            var heyMessage: PFObject = PFObject(className: "sendMessage")
                            heyMessage["messageSent"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
                            heyMessage["messageReceived"] = self.nameLabel.text
                            heyMessage.setObject(self.nextWeekButtonL.titleLabel!.text!, forKey: "message")

                            heyMessage.save()

                    var message = Message(sender: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, message: self.nextWeekButtonL.titleLabel!.text!, time: NSDate())

                    self.array.append(message)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }  } }   }  } }
```

I have tried to use a dispatch async with main queue, as well as different solutions to add the object to Parse, but the "else" after the check if the array contains, is executed as many times as the array does not contain.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Could you clean up your code a bit and add the remaining closures? It would help diagnose the problem if we could see the whole function.

Comment: I have updated the code with the remaining closures. Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you `array2.append(message3.message)` instead of `array2.append(textMessage3)` ?

Comment: @ Ryan Kreager: sorry for the late reply. Those are actually the same elements, as I define message3.message as being textMessage3 when setting var message3. No particular reasons though. There are no issues there when I println() it.